# Website availability not working on android app

Tags: android, eclipse, web

I use PhoneGap so I can display my webpage if it is available, and if it is not available I just use custom web page from asset. I have tryed several functions but none is working. Please help me and check what am I doing wrong.

```
    package com.test.project;

    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);

    if (isSiteAvailable()) {

        super.loadUrl("http://m.mywebsite.com", 10000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ima!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nemaaa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
public boolean isSiteAvailable() {

    try {
        URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection huc =  (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(); 
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        huc.connect(); 
        huc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        huc.setConnectTimeout(2000); // Timeout 2 seconds.
        int response=huc.getResponseCode();

        if ((response >= 400) || (response < 200))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("OOPSIE");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return false;
}

}
```

Manifest has permissions for internet and network, config.xml is allowing my website url, and everything works fine except checking connection. Please tell me what is the problem. SDK versions is from 8 to 17. I have restarted eclipse and cleared several times.

I have been reading topics all day, but I cant find problem.

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="rs.mujen.nekretnine"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="rs.mujen.nekretnine.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is "isSiteAvailable" called? What does it return? What exactly is not working? Any error or stack trace is welcome.

Comment: isSiteAvailable() is checked in onCreate() function. I am constantly getting message nemaaa! and it is displaying page from asset directory weather internet is working or not

Comment: Then isSiteAvailable is returning false. If you don't see a stack trace maybe the response from google is taking more than 2 seconds. Tell us what is the value of your "response" variable.

Comment: I assume that I can call isSiteAvailable() like I did because it is boolean and it is returning true or false

Comment: Yes you can. It is probably not the best idea as making a http request to an external site can take some time, but it has nothing to do with your code loading the wrong asset.

Comment: Is there any other function which is working so I could check if website is available, and if is I will loadUrl that website

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the connection time as network latency is irrelevant of time

The main problem was  setRequestProperty() on urlconnection with connection --> close which closes the connection

```
public boolean isSiteAvailable() {

try {
    URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection huc =  (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(); 
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    huc.connect(); 
    //huc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    //huc.setConnectTimeout(2000); // Timeout 2 seconds.
    int response=huc.getResponseCode();

    if ((response >= 400) || (response < 200))
        return false;

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("OOPSIE");
    e.printStackTrace();
 } 

 return false;
}
```

Hope these code works for you! :)

Comment: It is working on emulator now, but when I export it to apk and install on my Note, v4.0.4 I cant run it. I have icon of my program, but when I click on it I get message Application is not installed. When I install it on One X v4.1.1 I get message Waiting for debugger. SDK version in Manifest is from 8 - 17.

Comment: @user1306105 Try to re-install on Note or else connect Note via USB and try to install on it directly with Eclipse:)

Comment: I have uninstalled it from my Galaxy note, and then installed via Eclipse. I had clicked Run and selected my phone which was online. After install, icon of my program was on the phone, but when I click on it I get message Application is not installed.

Comment: I have removed       android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" from application tag in manifest, and my application is running now, but website checking is not working on emulator or phone now.

Comment: I have found one comment on this website> You need to move the call off your main thread. Android 4 enforces no network calls on the main thread to prevent ANR issues< What to do to fix this?